# Slicing the year from a year-mm-dd row in Python

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, slice

I am trying to slice a large object-type column in a pandas dataframe. 
All the dates in this column are on a "year-mm-dd" format and I would like first to replace it with only the "year" value and then convert it to a numeric column.

I tried to do the following :

```
for i in range(len(df.index)):
    df.age[i]=df.age[i][:4]
```

I directly get a warning and an error like this:

```
/home/nbuser/anaconda3_501/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/__main__.py:2: 
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas- 
docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-262-b01a66467d00> in <module>()
  1 for i in range(len(df.index)):
 ----> 2     df.age[i]=df.age[i][:4]

 IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

What I wanted to do if it worked, was then to convert this column from object to a numeric column by using:

```
df['age'] = pd.to_numeric(df['age'])
```

By putting a .to_dict prompt, I get :

Input : 
    df['age'].to_dict() 
Output: 
    {0: '1966-04-08', 1: '1965-05-14', 2: '1965-08-12', 3: '1968-02-15', 
    4: '1968-08-08', ...} I cut the rest as there are more than 16000 values

Plus, when I get the dtype I get : 
Input: 
    df['age'].dtype
Output: 
    dtype('O')

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: see related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31797249/extracting-year-using-pandas-datetimeindex-but-getting-error

Comment: thanks I'll look into that

Comment: Can you post what `df['age'].dtype` shows, and what the format of the column is, personally I'd convert to `datetime` and then just do `dt.year`

Comment: So df['age'].dtype returns : dtype('O')
the format of the column is "yyyy-mm-dd" , for example : "1967-12-25"

Answer (score 2):

You can try with one of these 2:

```
df['age'] = df['age'].astype(str).str.split('-').str[0].astype(int)
df['age'] = df['age'].astype(str).str[:4].astype(int)
```

Comment: @AyeAye you are welcome, please consider to accept the answer  by clicking on the tick on the left of the answer https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work  :)

Answer (score 1):

If your dates are in a column called 'age':

```
import datetime
df.loc[:,'age'] = df.loc[:,'age'].map(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(str(x),'%Y-%m-%d').year)
```